# Android app display in running processes

Tags: android, android-service, android-build

I'm writing an android app which includes a service. However, when I run this app and go into the settings->Downloaded, It shows my app. When go to settings->running, it doesn't display my app. Why? I don't think android kills the app immediately after closing an app.

Also, my other question is I see "1 process and 1 service" displayed write below the running apps. However, I don't see that with my app. All I see something like 7.88MB. Does anyone have any idea what changes I need to do in order to make my app display something like "1 process and 1 service" similar to other apps?

Comment: did you launch your app? And do you have an activity that starts your service?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have a main activity which starts the service.

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong. I just tried my other apps with service, and I was able to see "1 process and 1 service" etc in settings. Thanks.